# RELATED Function in DAX does not shows me related tables

Tags: powerbi

I have a Projects table related with the Employees table. So one employee can be the group leader in many projects. The relation is between Projects.GroupLeader field and Employees.ID field
In the Products table i'm trying to add a new column to show the name of the group leader using this

Group leader = RELATED(Employees[Name]) but this does not works. In fact the intellisense of RELATED does not shows me the Employees table.

Any idea please?

regards

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved. I had not the relation active in my model

Answer (score 1):

I had the same symptom, but in my case the problem was that the related table had duplicates. Check for duplicates if you are stuck!

Hope that helps!